# FileOutPutStream not creating the filepath

Tags: java, android

```
private byte[] convertStreamToBytes(InputStream inputStream){
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            String filename = DataUtil.hashFilename(getDocumentUri(), getFileName()); 
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + AESConstants.APOLLO_DOWNLOADS_NC_DIR;
            //String path = context.getFilesDir() + folder;
            File dir = new File(filePath);
            dir.mkdirs();
            filePath += filename;
            File file = new File(filePath);{
                AESLog.log(TAG, "filePath:: "+filePath);
                if(file.exists()){
                    AESLog.log(TAG, "File Exist :: "+filePath);
                    boolean deleteStatus = file.delete();
                    AESLog.log(TAG, "deleteStatus:: "+deleteStatus);
                }
            }
            if (inputStream == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
                int numread = inputStream.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            } while (true);
            out.close(); 
            //inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }finally{
            try{
                if(null !=  inputStream){
                     out.close();
                 }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am getting all file from an Api, the code above is to create a `filepath` and save the file in that particular path.

It was working fine until now. Issue happening when creating a `filepath` like `"/storage/sdcard0/apollodownloads/nc/852945139"First.py".rtf"` this. FileOutStream object null returning when creating this path. Whats the issue happening?

Comment: There is a single `return` statement in the code you posted, and it does `return null`. How could this method return anything other than null? Also, stop catching exceptions and doing nothing in the catch block. That hides the exception, and prevents you from knowing what problem was encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your path, when it has special symbols , like *"* in your case

Escape the path something like this:

```
"/storage/sdcard0/apollodownloads/nc/852945139\"First.py\".rtf";
```

Details about escaping can be found *[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)*

Comment: In some android devices the file is creating with this name itself like '852945139"First.py".rtf', but in some android devices it is not creating this particular file and throwing null